# winspool.drv not setting Default Printer

Tags: c#, .net, driver, printers

I am having some problem with winspool.drv. I have 2 machines and on both of them I have identical code and same winspool.drv.

In my .Net application, I have this code

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
```

This set the default printer to whatever name I pass in and then I would get paper sources information from it.

However, on one machine this call is unsuccessful as it returns false and on other it return true and then I able to access paper sources correctly.

Could anyone please tell me how can I find out why the call to SetDefaultPrinter(..) method is unsuccessful.